# Why integer zero does not equal long zero?

Tags: c#, .net

A strange piece of code I've just discovered in C# (should also be true for other CLI languages using .NET's `structs`).

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    int a;
    long b;

    a = 0;
    b = 0;

    Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b)); // False
    Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(0L)); // False
    Console.WriteLine(a.Equals((long)0)); // False
    Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(0)); // True
    Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(a)); // True
    Console.WriteLine(a == b); // True
    Console.WriteLine(a == 0L); // True

    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine(b.Equals(a)); // True
    Console.WriteLine(b.Equals(0)); // True
    Console.WriteLine(b.Equals((int)0)); // True
    Console.WriteLine(b.Equals(b)); // True
    Console.WriteLine(b == a); // True
    Console.WriteLine(b == 0); // True
    }
}
```

Two interesting points here (assuming that `a` is `int` and `b` is `long`):

1. `a != b`, but `b == a`;
2. `(a.Equals(b)) != (a == b)`

Is there any reason why comparison was implemented this way?

Note: .NET 4 was used if it makes any difference.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx

Comment: IEEE754 allows for "postive zero" and "negative zero". They're supposed to compare equal (e.g. via `==`), but do need to be distinguished in some cases, which is why there's other options like using `.Equals()`

Comment: @MarcB: These aren't floating-point.

Comment: Note that in the case of `a == b`, the language rules are that the operands are promoted to a common numeric type. In this case, `a` is promoted to `long`. See section 7.3.6.2 of the [specification](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029) if this interests you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In general, `Equals()` methods are not supposed to return true for objects of different types.

`a.Equals(b)` calls `int.Equals(object)`, which can only return true for boxed `Int32`s:

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj) { 
    if (!(obj is Int32)) {
        return false;
    }
    return m_value == ((Int32)obj).m_value; 
}
```

`b.Equals(a)` calls `long.Equals(long)` after implicitly converting the `int` to a `long`.
It therefore compares the two `long`s directly, returning true.

To understand more clearly, look at the IL generated by this simpler example (which prints True False True):

```
int a = 0;
long b = 0L;

Console.WriteLine(a == b);
Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));
Console.WriteLine(b.Equals(a));
```

---

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0001:  stloc.0     
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0003:  conv.i8     
IL_0004:  stloc.1     

IL_0005:  ldloc.0     //Load a
IL_0006:  conv.i8     //Cast to long
IL_0007:  ldloc.1     //Load b
IL_0008:  ceq         //Native long equality check
IL_000A:  call        System.Console.WriteLine    //True

IL_000F:  ldloca.s    00            //Load the address of a to call a method on it
IL_0011:  ldloc.1                   //Load b
IL_0012:  box         System.Int64  //Box b to an Int64 Reference
IL_0017:  call        System.Int32.Equals
IL_001C:  call        System.Console.WriteLine    //False

IL_0021:  ldloca.s    01  //Load the address of b to call a method on it
IL_0023:  ldloc.0         //Load a
IL_0024:  conv.i8         //Convert a to Int64
IL_0025:  call        System.Int64.Equals
IL_002A:  call        System.Console.WriteLine    //True
```

Comment: So `==` in this case is logically equivalent to long.Equals because of the implicit conversion?

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy: `==` is a different beast entirely.  It gets compiled to a dedicated IL instruction (`ceq`)

Comment: Would that not still force an implicit conversion to a common type, or am I oversimplifying it? My IL knowledge is limited at best.

Comment: The bad thing is that due to this approach we do not have uniform solution and it could lead to unusual bugs. Since compilers generally treat .NET's "primitive" types a little more special than other types, shouldn't they be implemented to always return correct results?

Comment: @paulius_l: I don't see your question.  All behavior here is correct according to the spec; the only non-obvious part is the implicit conversion to `long`.  What do you want to change?

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference for why there's an implicit conversion. Or put another way why does the overload resolution give `Foo.Bar(long)` instead `Foo.Bar(object)` when the argument is a smaller integral type.

Comment: @ConradFrix: The implicit conversion from `int` to `long` is more preferable to the boxing conversion from `int` to `object` (because it doesn't box).  I'll try to find that in the spec.

Comment: I checked how it was implemented using decompiler and that was the reason why I came up with this question. I understand that this is the way. But in my opinion 0 should always equal 0 and same goes with other numbers.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks but I think I found it. §7.3.6 Numeric promotions

Comment: @paulius_l: `Equals()` compares _types_, not just values.

Comment: @ConradFrix: No; that's for built-in operators, not for implicit conversions.  It's http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691339%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @ConradFrix, implicit numeric conversions are 6.1.2

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: I'm referring to conversion priority for overload resolution, which is §7.5.3.4ff

Comment: @SLaks Yeah I realized it when I went to confirm the section

Comment: @SLaks hmm for §7.5.3.4 to hold the conversion from `Int32` to `Int64` would need to be an identity conversion. I don't think it is. I think this bullet from §7.5.3.2 is what I was looking for; "for each argument, the implicit conversion from EX to QX is not better than the implicit conversion from EX to PX". While it doesn't call out that Int32 to Int64 is *better* than boxing an Int32, its probably because that's kinda obvious (which is what you said to begin with)

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same because even simple types are inherited from System.Object - they are actually objects, and different object types, even with the same property values are not equal.

Example:

You could have a Co-Worker object with only one property: Name (string) and a partner object with only one property: Name (string)

Co-worker David is not the same as Parner David.  The fact that they are different object types sets them apart.

In your case, using .Equals(), you're not comparing values, you're comparing objects. The object isn't "0"  it's a System.Int32 with a Value of zero, and a System.Int64 with a value of zero.

Code sample based on question in comment below:

```
class CoWorker
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Partner
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   CoWorker cw = new CoWorker();
   cw.Name = "David Stratton";
   Partner p = new Partner();
   p.Name = "David Stratton";

   label1.Content = cw.Equals(p).ToString();  // sets the Content to "false"
}
```

Comment: Then why does `0L.Equals(0)`?

Comment: @SLaks - Sorry, I was still typing, and of course, your answer was clearer, better, and got to the point quicker.  +1 to you.  :P

Comment: What would happen if you were to implement `CoWorker.Equals(Partner)` or `Partner.Equals(CoWorker)`

Comment: I just whipped up a sample xaml app to test it, and it returns false.

Comment: @DavidStratton Do your overloads get called?

Answer (score 0):

There is also the issue of narrowing or widening conversion. A `long` zero is always equal to an `int` zero, but not the other way around.

When a long is compared to an int, only the least significant 32-bits are compared and the rest are ignored, thus the `int.Equals(long)` operation cannot guarantee equality even if the lower bits match.

```
int a = 0;
long b = 0;

Trace.Assert(a.Equals((int)b));     // True   32bits compared to 32bits
Trace.Assert(a.Equals((long)b));    // False  32bits compared to 64bits (widening)
Trace.Assert(b.Equals((long)a));    // True   64bits compared to 64bits
Trace.Assert(b.Equals((int)a));     // True   64bits compared to 32bits (narrowing)
```

Also consider the case where the lower 32-bits are equal, but the upper ones are not.

```
uint a = 0;
ulong b = 0xFFFFFF000000;
Trace.Assert((uint)a == (uint)b);  // true because of a narrowing conversion
Trace.Assert((ulong)a == (ulong)b);  // false because of a widening conversion
```

Comment: That is correct, but not really relevant.  The reason it returns false is purely that it's a different value type.  The same would hold for `int` and `uint`.

Comment: So why does `long.Equal(int)` return true? It is not strictly an issue if type, but also if the bits *can* be compared.

Comment: Because of the implicit conversion.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Operator and method overloads, as well as conversion operators, are evaluated at compile time, unlike virtual-method overrides which are evaluated at run-time.  The expression `someIntVar.Equals(someNumericQuantity)` is completely unrelated to the expression `someObjectVarThatHoldsAnInt.Equals(someNumericQuantity)`.  If you were to pretend the virtual method `Object.Equals` has a different name (like `IsEquivalentTo`), and substitute that name every place the virtual method is used, this would be much clearer.  An integer zero may be numerically equal to a long zero, but that does not mean they are semantically equivalent.

Such a separation in meaning between `Equals` and `IsEquivalentTo`, incidentally, would also have helped to avoid murkiness in the definition of the latter.  It's possible to define a meaningful equivalence relation for arbitrary objects: storage location `X` should be considered equivalent to storage location `Y` if the behavior of all members of the former will always be equivalent to the corresponding members of the latter, and the only way to determine whether `X` and `Y` refer to the same object would be to use Reflection or `ReferenceEquals`.  Even though `1.0m.Equals(1.00m)` is and should be true, `1.0m.IsEquivalentTo(1.00m)` should be false.  Unfortunately, the use of the same name for the object equivalency-test method and the `Decimal` numerical-equality-test method led Microsoft to define the former to behave like the latter.

Answer (score -1):

because Equals compares objects and the a and b objects are different. They have the same value but are different as objects

This link may help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Wrong; `Equals` is supposed to test value equality.

Comment: @SLaks - true, but it also tests that the objects are of the same type as well.  That is, `Equals(object o)` on the `int` struct is essentially equivalent to `return (o is int) && ((int) o == this)`

Comment: That is true, but it still doesn't answer the question (Why does `0L.Equals(0)`?)

Comment: Dont know, I found this:  the conv.i8 instruction does get called for the line long longZero = 0L.

on this link: http://www.mikelindegardeonline.com/2011/02/09/c-literal-number-suffixes/

maybe the long zero is treated differently by the complier

Answer (score -1):

C# doesn't do automatic casting. Equals function compares types as well as values. Much like === in JS.

Comment: Then why does `0L.Equals(0)`?

Comment: I am too lazy to check, but I am pretty sure that 0L.Equals((int)0) would fail.

Comment: So that answers your first question. Doesn't it?