# Assert.AreEqual fails for int and ulong but not long and uint

Tags: c#, .net

Well, I hope my processor is not burned, because:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void tenEqualten()
    {
        Int64 a = 10;
        UInt32 b = 10;
        Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
    }
```

works just fine, but this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void tenNotEqualten()
    {
        Int32 a = 10;
        UInt64 b = 10;
        Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
    }
```

fails miserably.

Have you got same results, or is it just me?
If yes, any ideas, why?
If this is known issue for .Net 4.5 than sorry for spam, but I could not find that as a bug.

edit: I found a duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420288/why-integer-zero-does-not-equal-long-zero) and an explanation [here](http://blog.coverity.com/2014/01/13/inconsistent-equality/#.VGKK3TTF8vk)

Comment: `Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<10 (System.Int32)>. Actual:<10 (System.UInt64)>`. Use e.g. `Assert.AreEqual(Convert.ToUInt64(a), b);` instead. Result would be the same using Framework 3.5.

Comment: a.Equals(b) : Suspicious comparison: there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both 'int' and 'ulong'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first method you are calling `Assert.AreEqual<T>(T expected, T actual)` where `T` is of type `Int64`, this is because UInt32 is implicitly castable to Int64. It is the same effect as if you did

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void tenEqualten()
    {
        Int64 a = 10;
        UInt32 b = 10;
        Assert.AreEqual(a, (Int64)b);
    }
```

That is why the first version passes.

In the second version you are calling `Assert.AreEqual(object expected, object actual)` which fails because they are different types and therefor not "equal".

You could make your first version act like your second version by putting the two numbers inside a `object` this would let you use the same overload of Assert.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void tenEqualten()
    {
        Int64 a = 10;
        UInt32 b = 10;
        object c = a;
        object d = b;
        Assert.AreEqual(c, d);
    }
```

This method will fail exactly the same way your `tenNotEqualten` method will fail.

Answer (score 9):

Look at [the widening table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1e94s7e.aspx).

```
Integer -> Integer , Long, Decimal, Single, Double
UInteger -> UInteger , Long, ULong, Decimal, Single, Double
```

How does this relate to your code?

When you compare `long` (`Int64`) with `uint` (`UInt32`), the `uint` can fit a `long` so there's no problem here.

However when you compare `int` (`Int32`) with `ulong` (`UInt64`) you can see that there is no implicit widening available: they don't fit in eachother.

You can see this more clearly by just looking at the method resolution done by intellisense:

[image]

[image]

And finally:

```
object c = (int) 10;
object d = (ulong) 10;
Console.WriteLine (c == d);
```

will yield `false`

Answer (score 7):

`UInt32` can be cast to `Int64` but `UInt64` can not be cast to `Int32` as it would not fit.
You would get a compilation error on the `c == d` check in the example below.

```
Int64 a = 10;
UInt32 b = 10;

Console.WriteLine(a == b);

Int32 c = 10;
UInt64 d = 10;

Console.WriteLine(c == d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the System.Convert.ToUInt64 method to force the conversion from Int32:

```
[TestMethod]
public void tenNotEqualten()
{
  Int32 a = 10;
  UInt64 b = 10;
  Assert.AreEqual(Convert.ToUInt64(a), b);
}
```

Also, it is good practice when using the generic Assert methods to specify the generic parameter to avoid conversion issues. The following throws a more readable compile time error:

```
Assert.AreEqual<UInt64>(a, b);
```

> The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert.AreEqual(ulong, ulong)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'ulong'