# Why is Negative Zero equal to Positive Zero?

Tags: c#, signed

In computer programming, there exists a positive and negative zero. This may not come as a shock to you, but what is odd is the apparent fact that positive zero is equal to negative zero. Here is an example:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int positive = 0;
        int negative = -0;
        Console.WriteLine(positive == negative);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Output shows as "True".

As for everyone apparently flooding comments with "Int defaults to 0." I should point out that float's and doubles do the same thing, returning true for equality amongst negative and positive zero.

I suppose this may have something to do with the concept of graphing, which negative and positive zero would exist orthographically within the same dimensional point. Or is there another reason for the equality between them?

Comment: There is not negative zero of `int` type.

Comment: In some number theories this may be true but binary speaking the two are exactly the same.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint after `negative`'s value has been set then you will see its value is `0`.

Comment: @PetSerAl The same is returned for floats, as well. Explanation?

Comment: Do you see a reason that they should _not_ equal one another?  The only usable distinction I know of is that `1/(-0) === -Infinity` and `1/0 === Infinity`.  However when you're comparing the two they _are_ the same value, they just contain information that indicates how they originated.

Comment: If I look from my side: you owe me nothing (0), I owe you nothing (-0). It is the same.

Comment: @zyklus - It's simpler than that. The value is never -0 in the first place. So, the final code is seen as `Console.WriteLine(0 == 0);`

Comment: @Krythic Explanation of what do you want? Compiler just follows specification: **7.10.2 Floating-point comparison operators** *Negative and positive zeros are considered equal.*

Comment: @Lee -- I'm assuming the _meaning_ of the question.  Ignoring the fact that this is C#, some languages do have a `-0` value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A negative `int` is done using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). That is, invert the bits and add one. Regardless of the bit length, if you do this with a zero value, you get zero back.

For example `0000` flipped becomes `1111` and adding `1` rolls over back to `0000`.

This is by design to eliminate the redundancy of having two zeroes.

With `float` and `double`, according to [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) there are technically both `+0` and `-0`, but they are considered equal.

Comment: An for a float? Just flip the sign bit?

Comment: Absolutely correct, @Krythik you may take a look at how processors do basic calculation operations (alu) if you have in future similar questions

Comment: I felt as though this was the best reasoning for the equality, even if most compilers would optimize it away to straight-zero.

Answer (score 4):

They're equal for the same reason they are equal in math. -x is equivalent to -1*x. Well, 0 times anything is zero. This is equivalent to -1*0 = 0.

Also, when you say "In computer programming, there exists a positive and negative zero." Well, *yes* for 1s complement, but not for twos complement. I don't think any architectures these days use 1s complement.

> "Or is there another reason for the equality between them?"

For the same reason I said above. I don't think I'd want to live in a world where this happened.

```
int x=0; 
int y= -1*x;
if (y == x) //false
```

That would cause an awful lot of bugs.

Comment: "0 times anything is zero" -- `-0 * 0 == -0` :)

Comment: "I don't think I'd want to live in a world where this happened." +1 for that sentiment.

Comment: Since this topic discussed many times already - `Equals` behave more interesting than `==` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420288/why-integer-zero-does-not-equal-long-zero (and you may actually live in such world :) )

Answer (score -3):

Read about how negative numbers are represented by the CPU

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement